# calculating tip in model, putting the method in controller and then displaying it in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I am struggling to figure out how to calculate a tip and display it in show page.

It's a typical scaffold rails, ie, `rails g scaffold Tippy tip:float cost:decimal` ...

This is what I currently have in the model but it's not working:

**Model**

```
class Tippy < ApplicationRecord

    def self.calculation_of_total_cost 
        @price + (@tip + @price)
    end

end
```

]

```
**edit**

def calculation_of_total_cost 
    cost + (tip * cost)
end
```

**Show.html.erb**

```
<p>
  <strong>Tip:</strong>
  <%= @tippy.tip %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Cost:</strong>
  <%= @tippy.cost %>
</p>

<p>Total Cost:</strong>
    <%= @tippy.calculation_of_total_cost %>
</p>
```

**Controller Show's Method**

```
  def show
    @calculation_of_total_cost 
  end
```

This is the error I get:

```
NoMethodError in Tippies#show

undefined method `calculation_of_total_cost' for #<Tippy:0x007fd5abf8cab8>
```

How do I fix this in the standard way so in future I understand how to write methods in models, put it in controllers, and display it in views?

(I understand that there are multiple ways of displaying it, I'm just asking for the "standard" way to move forward on)

Comment: You should use instance `calculation_of_total_cost` method instead of a class one.

Comment: @llya, ie, get rid of 'self' part of the method in the model?

Comment: @Ilya, just did that right now, and this is the error I get now `undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: don't use instance variables since they are undefined. Use just `price + (tip + price)` instead

Comment: @Ilya, is that what you're supposed to do for instances method in models? I.e, don't use `@`?

Comment: exactly. ActiveRecord creates getter and setter for each database field, you can access this attribute just by calling `attribute` method, without `@`

Comment: @Ilya, oh ... so that's why you never need to initialize it in Rails?

Comment: you need, but not in this case. I suggest you read some basic tutorials before asking, it will be more efficient:)

Comment: @Ilya, thank you for taking the time to answer my questions. just want to confirm that this is the standard way of doing calculations, ie, write it in model like this, put the def method's name in controller's action, and then display it in the appropriate view?

Comment: one more question, why you are doing `@price + (@tip + @price)`

Comment: @Pramod, that was a mistake. I changed it to `cost + (tip * cost)` ... were you referring to `price` vs `cost`? or the equation itself?